# .NET MAUI Secure storage values return null after app is closed or phone is asleep for 10 seconds

Tags: maui, .net-8.0, maui-blazor

As the title states, I have a .NET MAUI app that I am currently running on an iOS device. The app saves a token inside of secure storage like this:

```
await SecureStorage.Default.SetAsync("accounttoken", "token here");
```

I then use this token to authorize with an API used by the app, however, when I fully close the app or wait 10 seconds after my phone sleeps, all values stored in secure storage seem to get wiped. I know this because, when the following line hits, it returns null:

```
await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync("accounttoken");
```

I am not removing the token at any point, and have removed all custom lifecycle methods.  I even tested by adding dummy values to secure storage and those get wiped too.  Any ideas as to what might be happening?  As I understand it, values in secure storage should persist indefinitely.

Comment: Seems some known issue around this on .net 8.0, and some workarounds were posted here https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17706

Comment: You can try to change the code to `var secureValue = Task.Run(async () => await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync("accounttoken")).Result;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that as soon as the phone is unlocked, I am able to retrieve the values again (they are no longer null).  My assumption is that Secure Storage can't be accessed while the phone is locked or in the background.  I imagine this is intended behavior.